# SCOM Rule for Fake Alerts

Tags: scom, system-center

I am working on a tool to generate fake data for System Center Operations Manager for internal testing purposes. I wrote a script as part of a discovery that is able to create an instance of any class I want and make SCOM fake-discover it. Currently, I'm using a class for AD Printer. Now the next step is to somehow create alerts on behalf of the Printer. For this, I wrote a rule targeted at the AD Printer, which reads from the logs to detect when it should be fired. The logs are being written to from a PowerShell script. However, I see no results. But when I target the same rule to All Windows Computers, I see the alerts.

From what I understand the rule will run on all agents that have an instance of the target class. Since I fake-discovered the AD Printer on this agent (which also happens to be the Management Server), should the rule not run on this?

Any other suggestions on how I can achieve this are welcome as well.

PS. I probably cannot share any of my code as I am under an NDA, but I can clarify my approach further, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Powershell script should run on the agents which have instances of the AD Printer. I recommend you to check the OperationsManager event log for script errors. The easiest way to generate (fake) alerts is to set up a simple, Event-based text log monitor: one specific word can trigger the unhealthy state (which in turn generates an alert), while another word resets the monitor to the healthy state. You can specify criteria for both events. Look at [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinholman/2009/06/19/using-a-generic-text-log-rule-to-monitor-an-ascii-text-file-even-when-the-file-is-a-unc-path/) for further details.

Comment: Event log had no errors. It might have been an issue with the hosting relationship. I tried with another class that is inherited from a hosted class, and things are working well.